# pupppeteer js element not clicking even thou it is available in console

Tags: puppeteer

I have the following element in html.

```
<a title="Download photo" href="https://example.com/photos/GXqvtQh1N9A/download?force=true" rel="nofollow" download="" target="_blank" class="_1QwHQ _1l4Hh _1CBrG _1zIyn xLon9 _1Tfeo _2L6Ut _2Xklx"><svg class="Apljk _11dQc" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 32 32" width="32" height="32" aria-hidden="false"></a>
```

From the console when Chromium is open.
I can query it like so:

```
document.querySelector('a[title="Download photo"]');
```

I can create a reference to it:

```
var link = document.querySelector('a[title="Download photo"]');
```

I then can click on it like so:

```
link.click();
```

I try the same exact thing in Puppeteer.js in code.  Same page.

```
  for (const handle of getAllElements) {
    try {
      await handle.click();
    const downloadButton = await page.$('a[title="Download photo"]');
      downloadButton.click();
      await sleep.sleep(2000);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  }
```

The initial handle.click() works and it opens me to the page I'm discussing here.
But then downloadButton.click() doesn't function.
I've also tried page.click(downloadButton).
I've also tried:

const downloadButton = await page.$('a[title="Download photo"]');
  await downloadButton.click();

To ensure I'm working with the same page I visually do it while the page is on the screen.

Any ideas what's gong on?

Comment: `elementHandle.click()` returns a promise: it should be `await downloadButton.click()`.

Comment: I tried that same thing it just hangs.  I should have put that in the question, sorry @mbit

Comment: Is it clickable? For what I see it has no text.

Comment: Yes it's clickable.  https://unsplash.com/photos/GXqvtQh1N9A it's the download button on the top right.

Comment: the only difference from the link I sent is that it appears in a lightbox from original home page.

Comment: tested on the link you sent and it works fine. can you provide the exact page the issue occurs?

Comment: Here's my exact code.  Doesn't get past the first page before it happens.  https://github.com/impactcolor/scrapeTest/blob/master/test.js @mbit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned it opens a layer on top each time you click on the image. Also, `a[title="Download photo"]` needs to be relative to the `handle` not page. Here is the working code:

```js
for (const handle of getAllElements) {
    await handle.click();
    await handle.$eval('a[title="Download photo"]', el => el.click());
    //allow download
    await page._client.send('Page.setDownloadBehavior', {
        behavior: 'allow',
        downloadPath: './'
    });
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));
    //click on X to close the layer
    await page.click('._1NHYN');
}
```

Comment: any reason why you did handle.$eval instead of of handle.$ alone?  @mbit

Comment: @FabricioG `handle.$` only selects the element, then you have to pass it to evaluate. `handle.$eval` combines selection and evaluation in one function, it's simpler.